# Microsoft Graph and WPF user authentication - custom login form

Tags: c#, wpf, microsoft-graph-api, office365

I'm working on a reporting app that uses MS Graph - all is working fine and dandy but the customer would like to use their own existing login/authentication form design before the aplication lounch - they probably want to have a unified login look across their apps.
Plan is to incorporate their start-up login window but the question is how to pass the field data to Azure for authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Approach 1:Using Azure AD**

[Add company branding to your sign-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/customize-branding)  allows you to customize the appearance of the sign-in page with your company logo and custom color schemes.

**Approach 2:Using Azure AD B2C**

For this scenario, I recommend you to use [Azure AD B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/overview) which helps you to have complete control over UI customization. Customize every page displayed by Azure AD B2C when your users sign up, sign in, and modify their profile information. Customize the HTML, CSS, and JavaScript in your user journeys so that the Azure AD B2C experience looks and feels like it's a native part of your application.